# How to avoid renderPlot to run more than once when updating multiple sliderInputs?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid rendering the plot function below more than once when pressing the reset button, while allowing the plot to render when any of the sliders change.

So far the sliders update correctly.  Whenever a slider value changes, the plot is rendered as it's supposed to.  I would like to avoid the plot to render twice (one per updateSliderInput call) when I press the reset button.  This is a simple example and perhaps the delay is not as noticeable, but this problem is particularly nagging when many more inputs affecting the plot are updated programmatically and the plot takes a significant time to render.

***Reproducible example:***

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, clientid, session) {

  x <- reactive({
    input$slider1
  })

  y <- reactive({
    input$slider2
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(x(), y())
  })

  observe({
    if(input$resetButton != 0) {
      updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", value=30)
      updateSliderInput(session, "slider2", value=30)

    }
  })
})
```

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Example"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("slider1",
                  "X:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      sliderInput("slider2",
                  "y:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      actionButton("resetButton", "Reset!")
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: Maybe the key is to use renderUI to recreate all sliders at once if it's corresponding values change.

Comment: I had a similar problem here and got a good result:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630668/alternate-control-of-a-sliderinput-between-a-derived-value-and-user-selected-val